# asking for alternatives for "be held" for an event in an sentence

Tags: synonyms

> The original sentence
>   : The Olympic Winter Games 2018 will **be held** for 17 days from 9 to 25 February 2018.

I would like to ask for neat options other than **be held** there.
I am considering **take place, happen, occur** as alternatives, but I am not sure which of these are appropriate and what the differences are.

Thank you for your help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your suggested options are grammatical and essentially mean the same thing. My ear suggests, however, that "happen" and "occur" are not quite idiomatic, at least not in US English. What you are discussing is a planned event, and "happen" and "occur" may apply to unplanned events. Indeed, "happen" generally applies to unplanned events.

Some other alternatives that you might consider are **are scheduled for** and **are planned for**.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer very much. Now I've got the differences regarding being planned and not planned thanks to your answer. May I ask you what difference lies between the two alternatives of **be held** and **take place**?

Comment: "Be held" and "take place" are synonyms.

Comment: Thank you but I would like to know if there is any slight difference in nuance between the two.

Comment: No. There is no nuance involved.

Comment: If I am bothering you too much, I am really sorry. But, I don't get what it means that "There is no nuance involved". I was trying to find out any difference in meaning between "be held" and "take place" even though the difference is really minor. Do you mean the two phrases have the exact same sense? I thought "be held" is more about some event going on with some emphasis on the progressive sense and "take place" is more about the beginning of the instance of the event being held. Sorry to bother you much.

Comment: @Smart I have not found a reference that indicates any difference in meaning. Moreover, my experience is that the two expressions are used interchangeably. If you have a citation that indicates otherwise, I shall be glad to review it.

Comment: I got your point, now. I appreciate all your comments.